# Custom regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

Hi I need to match this format

```
N - Number

NN,NN
```

or

```
NN.NN
```

also

```
N,N and N.N
```

and combinations

```
N.NN and N,NN or NN,N and NN.N
```

Comment: It's customary on StackOverflow to provide a snippet of what you've tried (and been unable to get to work) to show that you've made an effort to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: My bad. Next time I'll try more :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
\d{1,2}(?:[.,]\d{1,2})?
```

**explanation:**

```
\d{1,2}   : one or two digits
(?:       : start non capture group
  [.,]    : . or ,
  \d{1,2} : one or two digits
)?        : end group, optional
```

Comment: Suggestion: Comment your pattern by using [IgnorePatternWhitespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(SYSTEM.TEXT.REGULAREXPRESSIONS.REGEXOPTIONS.IGNOREPATTERNWHITESPACE);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22);k(DevLang-CSHARP)&rd=true) that has an actual regex pattern comment escape of #. It also allows one to spread a pattern over multiple lines.

Answer (score 2):

Here's your regex:

```
\d{1,2}[.,]\d{1,2}
```

See it here in action: http://regexr.com?2vman

---

Here's a slightly different version:

```
\d\d?[.,]\d\d?
```

See it here in action: http://regexr.com?2vmaq

---

If you want to also match with out a decimal, use this:

```
    \d\d?[.,]?\d{0,2}
```

See it here in action: http://regexr.com?2vml4

Comment: Works great, but i forgot to mention one more condition. It can be just a number without , or . For example just 3

Comment: @user49126 - See the update to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why match it?

Just remove the commas and use the actual number:

```
Regex.Replace("8,675,309.02", "(,)", string.Empty) // Outputs 8675309.02
```

If this is a validation scenario, using [int.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19.aspx) will let you know if its valid.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with something like this:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d{1,2}[\.,]\d{1,2}");
```

Comment: No need to escape the `.` there inside the brackets...